# SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus splits tokens in reserved_tokens

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm just starting out with tensorflow and am trying to do something with a corpus of latex documents, for which I want to use a `SubwordTextEncoder` which uses single tokens for latex macros. A macro `\foo` is encoded as a token `"\<c<foo>"` to enforce the requirement that reserved tokens "contain a mix of alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters"

I have

- a list `comms` of macros occurring in the corpus, the very first entry of which is `"\<c<begin>"`.
- a list `seq` of dictionaries, each with an entry "tokens" containing a string of space-separated tokens representing a paragraph of latex; pre-encoded using the above encoding for latex-macros

I do:

```
def corpus_generator():
    for o in seq:
        yield o["tokens"]
encoder = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(corpus_generator(),4000,reserved_tokens=comms)
```

But when I test this encoder like such:

```
teststring = seq[0]["tokens"]
print(comms[0])
print(teststring)
encoded = encoder.encode(teststring)
for index in encoded:
    print("{} --> {}".format(index,encoder.decode([index])))
```

I get the following output:

```
\<c<begin>
\<c<begin> { definition } We call two mathematical objects \<m$< a \<m$> and \<m$< b \<m$> equal , ( written \<m$< \<c<eq> { a , b } \<m$> ) , iff there are no properties that discern them . \<c<end> { definition }
2178 --> \<c<b
2873 --> eg
1108 --> in
3491 --> >
605 -->  { 
611 --> definition
608 -->  } 
656 --> We 
644 --> call 
705 --> two 
891 --> mathematical 
888 --> objects 
606 --> \<m$< 
612 --> a 
609 --> \<m$> 
621 --> and 
606 --> \<m$< 
745 --> b 
609 --> \<m$> 
1434 --> equal
2227 -->  , ( 
724 --> written 
606 --> \<m$< 
659 --> \<c<eq>
605 -->  { 
3526 --> a
610 -->  , 
3527 --> b
608 -->  } 
613 --> \<m$>
671 -->  ) , 
642 --> iff 
672 --> there 
646 --> are 
798 --> no 
1841 --> properties 
624 --> that 
2900 --> discern
3461 -->  
1549 --> them
614 -->  . 
989 --> \<c<
1996 --> end
3491 --> >
605 -->  { 
611 --> definition
620 -->  }
```

...which notably splits (exactly) those tokens supposedly being reserved tokens... what am I doing wrong?